# How to describe a translation in a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Our instructor wants us to transform an star shaped image described by

$x(t) = cos(t)^3 + 1$

$y(t) = sin(t)^3 + 1$

to fit his three criteria which are

1. The object should appear in the third quadrant.
2. The object should be half the height it was originally.
3. The final image only has one point touching an axis

I came up with a 2x2 matrix: [-1,0,0,-1/2] and I can't figure out how to describe a translation as a linear transformation. I am thinking that I could just add a vector containing constants after the transformation to change the x or y components to translate the image, but I am unsure if this is a valid transformation and if so how to describe it properly.

[image: image to be transformed]

Comment: Technically a translation (by a nonzero distance) is an affine transformation, not a linear transformation.  Every linear tranformation sends the origin to itself.

Comment: If that is the case, how do you suppose I get the image to touch an axis at only one point?

Comment: It might help Readers (myself included!) to have a picture of the initial image to look at.  It might take me a bit to create one, if you haven't already done so.  I think the formulas $x(t) = \cos^3 t + 1$ and $y(t) = \sin^3 t + 1$ are the usual notation for what you describe.

Comment: Yeah, that is the image.

Answer (score 4):

As has been noted in the comments, a translation can’t be represented as a linear transformation—it doesn’t leave the origin fixed. It is an affine transformation, though. This can be represented by a matrix if you use homogeneous coordinates, but whether you really need to do so or not depends on what it is you want to accomplish. If what you need is the parametric equations of the transformed curve, you can do that just as well by adding a constant offset to $x$ and $y$ as you’ve proposed.