# How to use linear transformations to change an original image

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Our instructor wants us to transform a star shaped image that is described by:

$x(t)=cos(t)^3+1$

$y(t)=sin(t)^3+1$

to fit his three criteria using **linear transformations**. The criteria are:

```
The object should appear in the third quadrant.
The object should be half the height it was originally.
The final image only has one point touching an axis.
```

I came up with a 2x2 matrix: \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1/2\end{bmatrix} and it seems to meet the first 2 criteria, but I don't know what to do for the third criteria. [Here is the image that we need to transform.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcs8j.gif) I wasn't specific enough in my last question, so I got unsatisfactory answers. He **requires** us to use **linear transformations**, so an **affine transformation** is not what he wants us to use.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621743/how-to-describe-a-translation-in-a-linear-transformation.

Comment: Why to you ask the exact same question a second time?

Comment: because it is not the same question. I need to use only linear transformations, not affine transformations. I wrongly assumed that adding a vector with constants after transformation was a linear transformation, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get one of the points off the axes, I think you have to use a shear transformation.

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

(I am applying these to column vectors.)

Then do your vertical scaling, then your rotation by $\pi$ ( which you apparently understand already.)

Comment: Yeah, I believe that is what he was getting at. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! It seems to fit the criteria. :D I sheared it in the wrong direction, forgot a minus sign. :P tyvm! :)

Comment: @mikemo you can help shield this question from closure by narrowing the other question so that th solution you got fits even better. Once you do, be sure to mention in the above thread that you've narrowed the other question to distinguish the two. Whatever you do, don't make the answer you got there inapplicable!